# Color palette SAGA GIS

Tags: saga, color, color-ramp

Does anyone knows if it is possible to manually modify SAGA GIS colour palettes, for example using ColorBrewer references?

Comment: How have you modified your SAGA palettes so far?

Comment: Yes, manually, but I was asking if I can put the colorBrewer palette codes. I've been seeing SAGA GIS help, and it should be a way, but I did not find it...Thanks for answering @user30184

Comment: Could this article be helpful http://www.marinedataliteracy.org/grids/colscripts.htm?

Answer (score 4):

Overall Workflow

1. Download ColorBrewer RGB color list
2. SAGA - Colors - Lookup Table - Save .pal
3. SAGA - Colors - Graduated Colors - Load .pal

First, I visited [ColorBrewer2](http://colorbrewer2.org/#) website, and downloaded one of its Excel sheet. I chose 6 colors of Orange-Red sequence. (a part of sheet as below)

[image]

Second, I opened SAGA and loaded a DEM file. At Colors section, I started with **Lookup Table** and manualy set RGB codes into each 6 palettes.

[image]

After entering all colors, I pushed **Colors** button.

[image]

Then changed numbers of colors by **Counts** from 6 to 24. This palette was stored as .pal file.

[image]

Third, going back to **Colors** section, I changed the type from **Lookup table** to **Graduated colors**. And Loaded the color palette of 24 colors I have just saved. Then pushed **Apply**.

Below is outcome.

[image]